# Media player (-19,0) for playing lots of audio files from raw

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am plying all sounds from raw folder. Using playSound() and releasing sound after completion as well on error releasing sound. Still i am getting error(-19,0) after couple of sounds played using playSound().

```
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public static boolean playSound(final Context context, int resId) {

        if(releaseSound()){

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, resId);

        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.d("test", "Media player error :" + what + " extra:" + extra);

         if(what == 19)
            FireToast
                        .showToast(context,
                                "MediaPlayer error (Out of buffer). Please restart your application.");

                releaseSound();

                mp.release();
                mp = null;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (resId == 0) {
            FireToast.showToast(context, "File not found");
            return false;
        }

        // mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, resId);

        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null)
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        releaseSound();
                        FireToast.showToast(context,"MediaPlayer song completed.");
                    }
                });
            mediaPlayer.start();
            setPause(false);

            return true;

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }

public static boolean releaseSound() {
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.stop();

                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();

            }
            mediaPlayer = null;
            isPause = false;

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```